# WPDB insert guarda 0 en lugar del string

Tags: php, wordpress, insert

Estoy intentando guardar en una tabla utilizando `$wpdb->insert`, mi código es este:

```
$wpdb->insert('ordenes',
                array(
                      'user_id'=>11,
                      'seller_id'=>22,
                      'site_id'=>'USA',                             
                      'id_orden'=>333,
                      'items_id'=>444,
                      'titulo'=>'Prueba',
                      'cantidad'=>1,
                      'currency_id'=>'USD',
                      'precio'=>10,
                      'net_received_amount'=>8,
                      'date_created'=>'20-3-2019',
                      'date_closed'=>'20-3-2019',
                      'last_updated'=>'20-3-2019',
                      'expiration_date'=>'20-3-2019',                                                       
                      'order_status'=>'paid',
                      'total_amount'=>10,
                      'total_amount_with_shipping'=>10,
                      'paid_amount'=>10,                
                    ));
```

Para mi sorpresa se guarda 0 en `site_id`. Agrego:

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();
```

Y me devuelve esto:

```
Error en la base de datos de WordPress: []
INSERT INTO `ordenes` (`user_id`, `seller_id`, `site_id`, `id_orden`, 
`items_id`, `titulo`, `cantidad`, `currency_id`, `precio`, 
`net_received_amount`, `date_created`, `date_closed`, `last_updated`, 
`expiration_date`, `order_status`, `total_amount`, 
`total_amount_with_shipping`, `paid_amount`) VALUES (11, '22', 0, '333', 
'444', 'Prueba', '1', 'USD', '10', '8', '20-3-2019', '20-3-2019', '20-3-2019', 
'20-3-2019', 'paid', '10', '10', '10')
```

El único campo que me guarda mal es `site_id`. En la tabla es un `varchar` de 3, igual que `currency_id`.

Lo cursioso es que lo guarda perfectamente cuando hago:

```
$wpdb->get_results("INSERT into ordenes (user_id, seller_id, site_id, id_orden, items_id, titulo, cantidad, currency_id, precio, net_received_amount, date_created, date_closed, last_updated, expiration_date, order_status, total_amount, total_amount_with_shipping, paid_amount) values ('1', '22', 'USA', '3', '4', 'Prueba', '1', 'USD', '10', '10', '20-3-2019', '20-3-2019', '20-3-2019', '20-3-2019', 'paid', '10', '10', '10')");
```

Al hacer `SHOW CREATE TABLE ordenes` me devuelve:

```
CREATE TABLE `ordenes` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `site_id` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `id_orden` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `items_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `titulo` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `cantidad` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `currency_id` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
 `precio` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `net_received_amount` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_closed` datetime NOT NULL,
 `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
 `expiration_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `order_rating` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `order_rating_message` text DEFAULT NULL,
 `order_status` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
 `total_amount` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `total_amount_with_shipping` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `paid_amount` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `orden_md5` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
 `notificado` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `entregado` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `regalo_enviado` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

¿Como puedo solucionar este error?. Gracias!

Comment: Puede que sea de un tamaño menor, ¿sería posible que nos muestres el resultado de un **`SHOW CREATE TABLE ordenes;`**?

Comment: Cralo que si Cedano!, ahi lo agregue a la pregunta. Gracias!

Comment: ¿El `INSERT` que le mandas es **exactamente** el que presentas al inicio de la pregunta (usando valores directamente) o bien estás usando **variables** para setear los valores?¿Si intentas el `INSERT` directamente en el manejador de BD ocurre lo mismo, te pone ese campo en `0`?

Comment: Lo probe con valores directamente, exactamente como esta en la pregunta e inserta 0

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre es que tengas un `TRIGGER` que cambie el valor a `0`. ¿Si intentas otro valor, como por ejemplo `AAA` también lo cambia por `0`?

Comment: Puedes ver los `TRIGGERS` que hay mediante: `SHOW TRIGGERS;`, ahí te dirá si tu tabla tiene alguno, cómo se llama, qué hace...

Comment: Guando hago el insert con get_results funciona perfectamente. Ahi agregue el detalle en la pregunta.

Comment: Pero... esa es otra tabla: `meli_ordenes2`... y al principio hablábamos de la tabla `ordenes`

Comment: a efectos de la explicacion resumi a ordenes pero siempre se llamo meli_ordenes2. De todas maneras encontre la solucion, cambie el nombre de la coumna de site_id a siteid y funciono!

Comment: Algo raro hay con tus tablas o con tus columnas. La columna tal y como la pones desde el principio debería funcionar. Lo único que podría cambiar eso sería un `TRIGGER` o que estés revisando una tabla que no es o que la tabla esté en otra base de datos o cosas así.

Comment: Hice SHOW TRIGGERS; como me comentaste y no arrojo nada. Pero el problema aparentemente viene de antes porque como muestro en la pregunta ya WP manda el insert 0.

Comment: No sé, tampoco el error dice gran cosa, no dice por ejemplo la causa del error, lo cual me parece extraño, un mensaje de error que no diga la causa me parece muy poco útil. No sé si en WP hay una forma de mostrar el error completo. Si no, puedes activar el modo `DEBUG` temporalmente y ahí sí debería ponerte en pantalla cuál es la causa del error en sí. Si le mandas la consulta con los datos ya  a mano, no puede ser que te cambie ese dato por un `0`, si fuera una variable OK, se puede cambiar en el flujo del programa, pero un dato a mano, muy difícil.